# Problem with S3 clone provider and file upload

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I am working with S3 clone, which, according to the documentation, has the same API as AWS S3. It's called Bluvalt: [S3 REST API](https://kb.bluvalt.com/kb/s3-apis)

Firstly, I created a working solution using Amazon S3 and it worked fine. However, when I have switched to S3-clone, the new provider is not detected with the new access key and secret. Here's the error I'm receiving:

```
An error has occurred, The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidAccessKeyId;
```

However, when I execute the file upload using AWS CLI it works fine. I have figured out that I have to add the endpoint to my Spring configuration.

I'm using `spring-boot-starter-aws` for connecting and operating.

Here are my properties:

```
cloud:
  aws:
    stack.auto: false
    region:
      static: ${S3_REGION}
    credentials.accessKey: ${S3_ACCESS_KEY}
    credentials.secretKey: ${S3_SECRET_KEY}

my-app:
  awsServices:
    bucketName: ${S3_BUCKET_NAME}
```

Is there a way to replace AWS endpoint with my provider?

Comment: I think you should provide more details about s3-clone. Look like that one is not an official library

Comment: https://kb.bluvalt.com/kb/s3-apis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. Below I post my working solution:

```
AmazonS3ClientBuilder
 .standard()
 .withClientConfiguration(configuration)
 .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder
   .EndpointConfiguration(properties.getEndpointUrl(), properties.getRegion()))
 .withCredentials(credentialsProvider)
 .build();
```

Basically, you have to the following configuration to the client: `.withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(properties.getEndpointUrl(), properties.getRegion()))`

Answer (score 1):

From a [document](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/reference/html/appendix.html) of `spring-cloud-aws`. We have no way to set an s3 endpoint in a properties file.

As some useful topics:

[Spring Cloud: testing S3 client with TestContainters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53092222/spring-cloud-testing-s3-client-with-testcontainters)

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/issues/333